# Adding Zebra EMDK to React Native - Getting the warning message 'Could not find com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1'

Tags: java, android, react-native, sdk, zebra

I'm currently trying to develop a basic RFID scanning app for a Zebra device. but unfortunately im facing the following error. i try out every solution but still the error exist.

**ERROR:**

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/symbol/emdk/9.1.1/emdk-9.1.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/symbol/emdk/9.1.1/emdk-9.1.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/symbol/emdk/9.1.1/emdk-9.1.1.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/symbol/emdk/9.1.1/emdk-9.1.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

**Android/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() 
         maven {
          url = "https://zebratech.jfrog.io/artifactory/EMDK-Android/"
      }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"
```

**App/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

    implementation("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1")
    implementation("com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2")
        compileOnly 'com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1'
//implementation("com.symbol:emdk:9.1.1")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```